# What does it mean to combine XmlIgnoreAttribute and XmlAttributeAttribute?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I've inherited some code that declares several `private` fields with both `[XmlIgnore()]` and `[XmlAttributeAttribute()]`.  Is it safe to assume that `XmlIgnoreAttribute` takes precedence and I can just remove the `XmlAttributeAttribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XmlIgnore] takes precedence if you're using the XmlSerializer, so if this is what you're using to serialize those classes, then you can safely remove the [XmlAttribute] from the fields. But if it's possible that some custom serializer is being used, then you'd have to check with the rules for this other serializer as well.

Answer (score 0):

XmlAttributeAttribute will make the property an attribute instead of a node when serialized to XML. Ignore will simply ignore the property.

Comment: But what happens when you have both attributes *on the same variable*?